# Update an ArrayList<Station> with values from a TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Station>>

Tags: java, arraylist, treemap

I need to replace the outdated objects in `ArrayList<Station>` with the updated objects in `TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Station>>`.

TreeMap> only has a portion of the Station objects in ArrayList.

Anyone know a way to do this in a fast and smooth way? My application is time sensitive, the faster it can process it the better it is due to the big amount of data it is processing.

I can post here the code I've if it is of any help

**EDIT:**

Here's the code:

```
public ArrayList<Station> smoothPingPong(ArrayList<Station> dados){
    ArrayList<Station> pingPongs = new ArrayList<>();
    TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Station>> tmap = new TreeMap<>();
    int tmap_key = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<dados.size(); i++) {
        if(dados.get(i).getPingPong() == 1)     {
            pingPongs.add(dados.get(i));
        }
    }

    ArrayList<Station> next = new ArrayList<Station>();
    for(Station d : pingPongs)  {
        if(!next.isEmpty() && next.get(next.size() - 1).getId() != d.getId() - 1)       {
            tmap.put(tmap_key++, next);
            next = new ArrayList<Station>();
        }
        next.add(d);
    }

    if(!next.isEmpty())     {
        tmap.put(tmap_key++, next);
    }

    for(Integer a : tmap.keySet()){ 
        //Processes the treemap updating it
    }
}
```

Now I need to go back to the Stations in the ArrayList dados and update it with the Stations I've on the TreeMap.

Comment: *"I can post here the code I've if it is of any help"*... Yes, please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not creating new Station Objects then you don't need to update anything, the station objects share the same reference in all your collections.

In this case, you are just returning a subset of the Station Collection, but the objects themselves are the same.